# STOCK VALUE OF REQUEST INTO A VARIABLE

Tags: ssis

i want to stock the value of this result into a variable into SSIS, it seems like he took always 0 and not the value of the request :(

Any help please ?

my Variable :

"select max(Version) as version from [Pilotage_RRC_DEV].[dbo].[ACTIF_PILOTAGE_FLUX_ENTRANT] where Flux ='test.csv'"

[image]

Comment: I assume the query is used in "recuperer" Execute SQL Task? If so, screenshot of the main tab + the result set tab will provide insight into what is happening

Answer (score 0):

- Create a variable in package scope of type INT
- Then in the Execute SQL task on Control Flow tab you are using R`ecuperer la Version du Flux existant deja`, go to `ResultSet` and create a variable `MaxValue` and set the `VariableName` to `User::Variable`